# SQLAlchemy Update Operation not working when the list in the "IN" operator is huge

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am trying to change the value of the rows for which the ID is in the list "list_var"

```
    conn = sqlengine.connect()
    metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
    Table_var= sqlalchemy.Table('Table1',metadata, autoload_with = sqlengine)
    query = sqlalchemy.update(Table_var).values(column_var=2).where(Table_var.columns.ID.in_(list_var))
    res = conn.execute(query)
```

The above code works perfectly fine when the length of list_var is small but it gives the following error when the length is huge.

```
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Is there any work around for it?

Comment: If I remember correctly mssql limits the number of placeholders to the thousands, due to implementation details (might've been related to SP parameter count, which is 2100). Either create and use a temporary table, or a TVP (not well supported by most Python drivers).

Comment: since you asked for *any* work-around: split list_var in half and execute both halfs separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I split the list into smaller lists.
Below is the code

```
if(len(list_var)>1000):
     chunks = [list_var[x:x+1000] for x in range(0, len(list_var), 1000)]
     for chunk in chunks:
         query = sqlalchemy.update(Table_var).values(column_var=2).where(Table_var.columns.ID.in_(chunk))
         res = conn.execute(query)
```